# Sitefinity upgrade to 10.l2 lost access to blogposts

Tags: security, upgrade, sitefinity

I am currently trying to upgrade an 8.0 Sitefinity environment to 10.2.6602. This is my first time. The process worked smoothly for the most part but unfortunately as the title suggests I lost access to the blogposts section from the backend and am welcomed with the following when trying to access it:

*gERROR - Error: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): You are not authorized to access this page
   at Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinityRoute.CheckSecurity(HttpContextBase httpContext, PageSiteNode node)
   at Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinityRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)*

There was no specific issue in the upgrade trace log and I already checked the following:
- the blogs are still present in the database.
- the module seems to be succesfully installed.
- I can access the physical posts from the site.

All I can think off is an issue in one of the config files, if anyone has any advice it would be really helpful as I am at a bit of a loss as to what to try next. Could it be a membership issue?

Thank you for any input you might have.

Regards,
Al.

Comment: Do you have any non-default permissions on the blogs? I'd try to deactivate the Blogs module and activate it again.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, unfortunately deactivating and re activating the blogs module did not help (nor was uninstalling it and re-installing it to be honest).

I have custom permissions on the blogs through the securityconfig file:


Could that be it? I tried removing them though to no avail, I have a feeling something else is missing in another config file to allow those to take effect.

Comment: Opps, link to my config file: http://freetexthost.com/dhzcolf3pb

Comment: Did you restart the site after the changes in your config file?

Comment: @Alexh Can you check storageMode in web config and if it is either set to auto or database can you change it to <sitefinityConfig storageMode="FileSystem" /> and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Hi guys thank you for the replies, I got it to work last night finally by forcibly re-installing the blogs module putting the version number to null in the db. As to why it did not when I did the same from the back end..